# How to calculate perspective transformation using ellipse

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm very new to 3D image processing.i'm working in my project to find the perspective angle of an circle.
A plate having set of white circles,using those circles i want to find the rotation angles (3D) of that plate.

For that i had finished camera calibration part and got camera error parameters.The next step i have captured an image and apply the sobel edge detection.

After that i have a little bit confusion about the ellipse fitting algorithm.i saw a lot of algorithms in ellipse fit.which one is the best method and fast method?

after finished ellipse fit i don't know how can i proceed further?how to calculate rotation and translation matrix using that ellipse?

can you tell me which algorithm is more suitable and easy. i need some matlab code to understand concept.

Thanks in advance

sorry for my English.

[image]

Comment: Your case is very simple: just find all circles (`[L,N]=bwlabel(image)`), then walk through every circle (`level`) and calculate its gravity centre (`[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:size(image,1), 1:size(image,2)); idx = find(L == level); N = size(idx,2); Xc = sum(X(idx)) / N; Yc = sum(Y(idx)) / N;`). Now you can compare result with etalon by less square method to find transform parameters. If you know russian or use on-line translation, you can read some my thoughts about matrix coordinate  transforms [here](http://eddy-em.livejournal.com/6696.html).

Comment: And more: if you want to find all Euler's angles, you should use at least 2 cameras. In that case you should find edges of all ellipses (difference with binary image and its dilation, after that - `bwlabel`), approximate parameters of every ellipse (I recommend to read [this article](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.117.3465&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) and then by matrix operations calculate Euler angles (that would be more complex, than for 2D).

Comment: Thanks Eddy...But i need to find all eulers angles using single camera image(2D) with reference of another image(2D).can you suggest which one is best and fast algorithm for ellipse fit...i Don't know russian and can't translate on my own language also. That's may not useful for me.

Comment: Read the article in my second message. It give a very good approximation of ellipse and written in English. To find Euler's angles with good precision I advice you to make model first: scan an original image, make its transformation as it would be seen from some point, calculate properties of all ellipses (centres + semiaxes) and then try to calculate Euler's angles. I think, inverse model (calculate properties of ellipses by given camera position) will help you to develop direct algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

First, find the ellipse/circle centres (e.g. as Eddy_Em in other comments described).

You can then refer to Zhang's classic paper
  https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/zhang/calib/ 
which allows you to estimate camera pose from a single image if some camera parameters are known, e.g. centre of projection. Note that the method fails for frontal recordings, i.e. the more of a perspective effect, the more accurate your estimate will be. The algorithm is fairly simple, you'll need a SVD and some cross products.